# anyone know why lintr is marking the first string of my jupyter r kernels in red?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, jupyter, lintr

[image: screen shot of lintr marking my first character in red]

[image: screen shot of another example]

i just set up R to work with Jupyter notebooks in vscode but it is marking the first string of my kernels in red.

The message I get is:

```
Failed to run diagnostics: ! error in callr subprocess
Caused by error:
! Full file exclusions must be character vectors of length 1. items: 1 are not! lintr
```

if i uninstall languageserver package then it disappears but vscode asks me to reinstall it and then it comes back
how do i get rid of this?

Comment: Is this discussion relevant? https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues/343 (specifically: nathaneastwood wrote "Ok, so I decided to delete my .lintr file and recreate it. Now it would appear to be working. I know I tried this the other day with no joy so I am wondering if between the reinstallation of lintr and the recreation of the .lintr file it has been solved.")

Comment: i tried deleting and using default .lintr files but nothing happened. I'm not sure if i need to put a setting that will remove the red mark or write code differently. is the error message saying that i need to set up exclusions in the .lintr file?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the R code below to update the languageserver package to the latest development build:

```
    install.packages("languageserver", repos = c(
    reditorsupport = "https://reditorsupport.r-universe.dev",
    getOption("repos")
))
```

see https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues/343 for reference. It seems like this error was fixed via [REditorSupport/languageserver#610](https://github.com/REditorSupport/languageserver/pull/610).

I had this same error and this worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try to run the R code below:

> lintr::use_lintr(type = "tidyverse")

see https://github.com/r-lib/lintr/blob/main/README.md#lintr-file-example for reference.
I think it creates a .lintr file that defines a default behaviour for lintr within your project directory.So you might need to run the code above each time you have a new project